# create a form edit function php

Tags: php, forms, function

I created a function to display the content of a table. This is the function:

```
function query_tabel ($sql){
    $query = $sql;
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $kolomen_tellen = mysql_num_fields($result);
    if (!$result) {
        die("Error Query: " . mysql_error());
    }
    print "<table border=1>\n";

        print "<tr>";
            for ($column_num = 0; $column_num < $kolomen_tellen; $column_num++)
            {
                $fieldname = mysql_field_name($result, $column_num);
                print "<TH>$fieldname</TH>";
            }
            print "</tr>";

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
        print ("<TR>");
        for     ($column_num = 0; $column_num < $kolomen_tellen; $column_num++)
            print ("<TD>$row[$column_num]</TD>\n");
        print ("</TR>\n");
    }
    print "</table>";
```

it work and can call the function any time in any file.
But I want another function that creates an edit form with input fields.

This is my first draft:

```
function query_tabel_edit ($sql, $filename){
    $query = $sql;
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $kolomen_tellen = mysql_num_fields($result);
    if (!$result) {
        die("Error Query: " . mysql_error());
    }
    print "<table class=edit>\n";

        print "<tr>";
            for ($column_num = 0; $column_num < $kolomen_tellen; $column_num++)
            {
                $fieldname = mysql_field_name($result, $column_num);
                print "<TH class=edit>$fieldname</TH>";
            }
            print "</tr>";

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
        print "<form action=$filename method=post>";
        print ("<TR>");
        for     ($column_num = 0; $column_num < $kolomen_tellen; $column_num++)
            print ("<TD class=edit> <input class=edit type=text name=$row[$column_num] value=$row[$column_num] </TD>\n"); 
            print ("<TD class=edit> <input class=edit type=submit name=update value=edit> <TD>\n");
        print ("</TR>\n");
    }
    print "</table>";
}
```

So I added the edit link, works like a charm but how and where do I create and put the SQL line that modify the record.?

Any idea how to create this edit sql statement and do I need to put data sql line somewhere in my function or in the PHP file that calls the function?

Comment: *PSA:* The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it more or less like this. It is tough to make this completely flexible, because you need to know how to build your update statement. That means that you have to know which table to update and which fields. You cannot rely on what is in the HTML form, because someone might forge a fake form and post illegal field names, making you open for attacks.

I think the best way to do this, is to store the information about the table and fields being updated in the user's session, but since I don't know if you know about sessions, I left that out of here for now.

Note that I've used the `mysql` functions, because you are using them and I don't want to force you to change that, but they are deprecated and you are strongly adviced to change to mysqli or PDO.

Using mysqli you can also use prepared statements. But that's also something I leave for you to read about in the docs.

The most important change I have compared to your code, is that I used `mysql_fetch_array`, which returns an array of values that also contains the field names as keys. That way, you can use those names for your edits, and you will find those names in your `$_POST` data. From there, you should be able to puzzle a little more to get it working.

```
<?php

// This is how to do it in a single script: Check if a value is posted and 
// act on it.
// If you have separate scripts, you don't actually need this, although it's 
// still a good idea to thoroughly check the input to your scripts to prevent
// attacks from malicious users.

if (array_key_exists('id', $_POST)
{
  // Post data found. Update record.

  // Assuming id is an integer, I int-cast it. If it's not, make sure to 
  // properly escape it or you'll be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks!
  $id = (int)$_POST['id'];

  // You will need to validate if the posted field names are valid. You can
  // do this by specifying a list of updatable fields and then check if the 
  // posted values are in that list. 
  // You could also run query to get the field names from the database, so
  // so you will have more flexibility.
  // You can also store the fields to be updated in the session of the user
  // That will save you a query, but you'll have to read about sessions as well.
  $updatableFields = array('firstname', 'lastname');

  foreach ($_POST as $fieldname => $value)
  {
    // Validate the field names! You don't want field names that don't 
    // exist, or your query will break. Also, it will make you vulnerable 
    // to SQL injection attacks.
    if (array_search($fieldname, $updatableFields) !== false)
    {
      $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
      $update[] = "$fieldname = '$value'";
    }
  }
  $sql = 'UPDATE YourTable SET ' . implode($update) . " WHERE id = $id";
  // Execute statement.
}
else
{
  // Query your database here
  // <<code omitted>> 

  // Show edit form
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
    foreach ($row as $fieldname => $value)
    {
      $value = htmlspecialchars($value);
      $type = 'text';
      // Store the id in an hidden input, so you know which row to update.
      if ($fieldname == 'id')
      {
        $type = 'hidden';
      }
  ?>
    <label for="<?=$fieldname?>"><?=$fieldname?></label>
    <input type="<?=$type?>" id="<?=$fieldname?>" name="<?=$fieldname?>" value="<?=$value?>">
  <?php
    }
  ?>
    <input type="submit" value="save">
  <?php
  }

}
```